# What is the difference between `npm run-script build` vs `npm build`?

Tags: node.js, npm

When I run `npm build`, it gives this error:

```
npm WARN build `npm build` called with no arguments
```

So, what's the difference between `npm run-script build` and `npm build`?

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script) says: *This is the plumbing command called by npm link and npm install.
It should generally be called during installation, but if you need to run it directly, run: `npm run-script build`*

Comment: @Datz That documentation was erroneous. See [this PR](https://github.com/npm/cli/pull/5192) and [this issue](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/5185).

Answer (score 17):

`npm run-script` is a way to execute arbitrary commands specific to the project/package. Check your applicable package.json file, which will have defined what happens when you execute `npm run-script build` for that package. It may also include what happens when you run common commands, such as `npm run-script test`.

As you can see in [the documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script) for `npm run-script`, this arbitrary command can include arguments, which you need to refer to your package.json to learn more about.

`npm build` is not a unique command to the package, and is a native command that ships with npm, as you can see [in its documentation.](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/build)

Comment: I suspect that this answer was never accepted because it is just as confusing to *NPM Noobies* as the documentation. I came here because I did not understand when to use `npm run-script` and when to use `npm build` in the documentation. This answer gets me no closer to understanding.

Comment: Documentation link broken

Answer (score 15):

The best answer is in [this SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51358235/difference-between-npm-start-and-npm-run-start).

Basically...

`npm run` == `npm run-script`

Plus, certain common tasks are aliased so that the following are true...

`npm test` == `npm run-script test`

`npm build` == `npm run-script build`

For common tasks, use...

`npm start`

`npm build`

`npm test`

`npm restart`

And for all others, use...

`npm run <my-task>`

Comment: `npm build == npm run-script build`. I'm not sure what you mean by `==` but based on my interpretation of `==` that is incorrect. What do you mean by it?

Comment: It was true that `npm build` did the same thing as `npm run-script build` until npm v6, but that is no longer the case now.

Answer (score 2):

#### TLDR

- `npm build` is an old CLI command that `npm` stopped exposing via their CLI after version 6 of the CLI.
- `"build"` is a common name chosen by developers for the user-defined script that builds their project. Developers define this in their `package.json` file and run with some variant of `npm run-script build`. If this user-defined script is not defined in `package.json`, the `npm` CLI will throw an error, just as it does when a user attempts to pass any other non-existent user-defined script to `npm run-script`.

#### Alias in Wonderland

First of all, I'll try not to go down the rabbit hole, but let me get something out of the way. At the time of writing this, `run` is just an alias for [`run-script`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-run-script), as are `rum` and `urn`, believe it or not. In the remainder of this answer, I will just use `run-script`, since it seems to be the "main" name (and not an alias) for this command. But in any of the usages below, feel free in your mind to replace `run-script` with `run`, or even `rum` or `urn`, if you are feeling quirky.

#### `npm` is a CLI

OK great, what next? Well, to avoid confusion, let's separate our concerns and first focus on the difference between `npm COMMAND` and `npm run-script SCRIPT`, in general. Here I am just using `COMMAND` and `SCRIPT` to denote some arbitrary command/script, respectively.

First, think about what `npm` is. It's a [CLI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface) tool. And like any other CLI tool you can think of, it has some built in commands or "verbs". For example, if we do `npm ls`, we can see a list of installed packages. Here `ls` is the `COMMAND` or the "verb" passed to `npm`.

#### The `npm run-script` command

One of the commands i.e. verbs that the `npm` CLI supports is `run-script`. This particular command will:

> [run] an arbitrary command from a package's "scripts" object. If no "command" is provided, it will list the available scripts.

([source](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-run-script))

So for any user-defined `SCRIPT` you have in your `package.json` file, you can run it, using `npm`, by doing:

`npm run-script SCRIPT`

`SCRIPT` can be almost anything you like*. It's user defined. You can call a command `build` if you like, or you can call it `billy` or `bilbo`. Clearly, you want to call it something sensible. And that's why a lot of developers use the term `build` for a script which builds their project.

*There are some naming restrictions on the `SCRIPT` so it's not totally free-form. See [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/using-npm/scripts).

#### `npm build` and `npm run-script build`

Now that we understand `npm` is a CLI tool, we can finally tackle the problem of `npm build`. Here, we are passing `build` as the *verb* to the `npm` CLI. This is completely different to passing `build` as the name of a custom-script to run with `npm run-script build`.

Now, the question is, is the `build` command even a valid verb of the `npm` CLI? The answer is: it depends on the version of `npm` you are using:

- [Version 8](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands): There is NO build command.
- [Version 7](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands): There is NO build command.
- [Version 6](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands): There **is** a build command.

So `npm build` is only valid in version 6, and possibly earlier versions, of the `npm` CLI.

It's likely that NPM intentionally removed the `build` command from their CLI to avoid confusion. Many developers use `build` as the name of one of their user-defined scripts in `package.json`, so having another `build` verb in the `npm` CLI causes the two to be confused - hence questions like this one.

#### Tests

To confirm that `npm build` and `npm run-script build` are indeed different, I tested them on [Docker Playground](https://labs.play-with-docker.com/) for various `Node/npm` versions. Here are the results:

| Node Version | npm version | Result of `npm build` | Result of `npm run-script build` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `node:10.0.0-slim` | `npm@5.6.0` | No output (command apparently succeeded but didn't seem to do anything) | `npm ERR! missing script: build` |
| `node:12.0.0` | `npm@6.9.0` | No output (command apparently succeeded but didn't seem to do anything) | `npm ERR! missing script: build` |
| `node:18.6.0` | `npm@8.13.2` | `Unknown command: "build"` (the command failed) | `npm ERR! missing script: build` |

#### Old Source of Confusion

While writing this answer, I discovered [a bug](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/5185) in the `npm` version 6 docs, which, like many of us confused folk visiting this SO question, were erroneously conflating `npm build` with `npm run-script build` and adding to the confusion. I have since submitted [a PR](https://github.com/npm/cli/pull/5192) for this issue which has been merged. Hopefully it will be reflected in the `npm` docs soon.

---

Hopefully the links in this answer stay alive for a while, but please comment if they go stale.

Comment: In short "npm build" is a inbuilt command or as NPM creator calls it... it  is a lifecycle event (predefined) where as npm run-script is a task that executes a script and hence can be defined by user differently from the lifecycle event 'build'.

Comment: @vikaspachisia Are you proposing an alternative answer, or do you have criticism aimed at this answer? If the former, then please post your own answer. If the latter, then be more specific with your criticism. Thanks.

Comment: It was not criticism for sure. I was trying to add on to the answer provided by you. But if you think this should not be an add on, then I have no issues in posting it as another answer (different perspective) but not alternate to what was answered earlier.

Comment: Constructive criticism is welcome; adding your own answer is totally within the guidelines of this site.

Comment: I found this answer more suitable for beginner like me who try to understand between npm build and npm run-script.

Answer (score 0):

In short "npm build" is a inbuilt command or as NPM creator calls it... it is a lifecycle event (predefined) where as npm run-script is a task that executes a script and hence can be defined by user differently from the lifecycle event 'build'.