# Is there a difference between `npm start` and `npm run start`?

Tags: npm

I am able to run both the `npm start` and `npm run start` commands. I used [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) to create my application. To make configuration changes in the CSS module, I want to run `npm eject` but it throws an error.

The `npm run eject` command works however. I'm confused as to why `npm eject` did not work. Can I configure it to work?

Below is my `package.json` file:

```json
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
}
```

Answer (score 459, accepted):

`npm test`, `npm start`, `npm restart`, and `npm stop` are all aliases for `npm run xxx.`

For all other `scripts` you define, you need to use the `npm run xxx` syntax.

See the docs at https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script for more information.

Comment: like  i am new to this, i didn't clearly understood that one

Comment: What in particular didn't you understand?

Comment: i didnt understand like meant by aliases means?

Comment: With aliases I mean that `npm test` does exactly what `npm run test` does, `npm start` does exactly what `npm run start` does, and so on.

Comment: why start is aliase and build is not?

Comment: @user1912383 You'd have to ask the authors of npm. I suppose `npm start` is just used often enough to warrant an alias.

Comment: Actually, it also runs the `prestart` and `poststart` script, before and after the `start` script https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts

Comment: @hashlash That's true for `npm run *` too. `npm run foo` will run `prefoo`, `foo`, `postfoo`.

Comment: how about npm init and npm run init. Are they also exactly the same when you run them? If not, what's their difference? please point me to a good reference please. Thanks.

Comment: I think the x's were what were a bit confusing. The convention is normally * for a wildcard.

Answer (score 35):

`npm start` is the short form for `npm run start`. So, its one and the same thing.

Answer (score 19):

One interesting thing to note is,
If the `scripts` object **does not** have a `"start"` property in `package.json` file, `npm start` or `npm run start` from command line will run `node server.js` by default.

But if the `scripts` object in package.json has `"start"` property, it overrides `node server.js` and executes the command in `"start"` property.

See - https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-start#description

Answer (score 4):

Telling this because sometimes this can be help to someone.
Inside the jenkins pipelines you should use npm commands with "run"
ex- `npm run start`
if not the command will not be executed.

Comment: It's actually any minimal environment where you are lacking things like stdout (a true tty), such as in a minimal or stipped container. In these cases many aliases are actually non-existent; For example, when using Jenkins, Tavis-CI, or GitLab-CI, in various versions of their runners and containers - even with self-installed Node, you will find `npm test` fails with an error that the command is not found, and you'll need to set `npm run test`. 

This is a good point to make, so I upvoted you - its just not an answer to the question (obviously).