# How to resolve when create-react-app not responding in terminal

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I am unable to start react project using create-react-app. I waited for an hour
but there was no response in the terminal. I have also tried reinstalling node.js and run the 
following commands

```
-> npm cache clean --force
-> npm install -g create-react-app
-> npx create-react-app hello-world
```

But these didn't work.
My node version:10.18.0, npm version:6.13.4.

Comment: After running `npx create-react-app hello-world` you need to run `cd hello-world` and then `npm run start`, Did you do that?

Comment: This message was appear after running  npx create-react-app hello-world,  
Creating a new React app in C:\Users\suche\Desktop\hello-world 
Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes. 
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

I waited for an hour after running this but  there was no response in terminal.

Comment: Is the terminal still running? the app wont start after it is done, you need to follow the steps I wrote in my previous comment after the app is done creating.

Comment: The terminal is still running and no response found. app was not created completely.

Comment: I have had this issue a few times, I just closed the terminal and started again, some reasons that may cause this is poor/no internet connection, proxy firewall. hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a react application and make it running

Steps

1. Install Node js
2. Install create-react-app by running `npm i create-react-app` (add -g for install 
    globally) `npm i -g create-reaact-app`
3. Create a application by running create-react-app hello-world (can't use capitalised as create-react-app Hello-World you can read more [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2165))
4. Moving to the folder by running `cd hello-world`
5. Running the application `npm start` (Default port will be 3000, if anything is running in 3000 in terminal it will ask you to open in another port just type **y**, difference between npm start and npm run start [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51358235/difference-between-npm-start-and-npm-run-start))
6. Thats it your application will be running in the Port.

Comment: I have done first three steps. But after running npx create-react-app hello-word,there is no response in terminal.

Comment: Try using npm. It's weird that npx also should work. Try using npm and let me know

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed `create-react-app` globally. remove that globally from you system and upgrade your nodejs version [Upgrading Node.js to latest version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10075990/upgrading-node-js-to-latest-version?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top)

Try these steps-

1-Upgrade nodejs

2-
`npm uninstall -g create-react-app`

3-

```
npx create-react-app app_name
cd app_name
npm start
```

> Note- npx comes with npm 5.2+ and higher, see instructions for older npm versions

for your reference [reactjs documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/)

Comment: Yes, I upgrade nodejs and I have done first three steps. But after running npx create-react-app hello-word,there is no response in terminal.

Comment: @SuchetaSaha remove your proxy of local system and try