# npm ERROR after npm start on node / express

Tags: node.js, json, express, body-parser, npm-start

The index.js file has the following code as;

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const app = express();

app.use(morgan('tiny'));
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.json({
        message: 'Welcome!'
    });
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on port ${port}...`);
});
```

And I edited the package.json

```
"main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
```

The dependecies versions are:

```
"dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0"
  }
```

When I run `npm start` on terminal, the error shows like this:

`npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path E:\.....\package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\......\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! C:\Users\Mamun\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-04-15T10_03_09_445Z-debug.log`

What can I do? Please help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: you have to run `npm run start` instead of `npm start`

Comment: Make sure you are located in your directory with the `package.json` file. It seems you are not in it.

Comment: @DorianB for start it's ok to just use `npm start`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51358235/difference-between-npm-start-and-npm-run-start#answer-51358329

Comment: @MickaelB. Yes, my directory on terminal was wrong. Correcting this, I run again. Now it shows like this: `events.js:288
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3000
←[90m    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1309:16)←[39m
pm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! server@1.0.0 start: `node index.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! Failed at the server@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above...`

Comment: @mostafa.bd this means that port 3000 is already used by another process. Do you have your server already running somewhere else?

Comment: @OlivierKrull Yes, changed the port and now it works well. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you very much for all of your support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are getting here specifies on that line that the `package.json` file is not found :

> npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
>   'E:......\package.json'

You need to run your `npm start` command from the folder in which there is your `package.json` file.

Comment: Yes, got it. Thank you very much