# npm start not picking up updated package.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I am writing a node app from scratch, with the following **package.json**, which is pretty boiler-plate.

```
{
    "name": "myfirstnodeproject",
    "version": "1.0.1",
    "description": "Learning node",
    "main": "index.js",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
    },
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "request": "^2.88.2"
    }
}
```

I created **server.js** to look like this:

```
var http = require("http");

http.createServer((inRequest, inResponse) => {
    inResponse.end("Your IP Address is " + inRequest.connection.remoteAddress);
}).listen(9000);
```

When I started the app using `npm start`, it worked fine.

Then, I created a new file called **server_time.js**:

```
require("http").createServer((inRequest, inResponse) => {
    const requestModule = require("request");
    requestModule(
        "http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/America/New_York",
        function (inErr, inResp, inBody) {
            inResponse.end(
               `Hello from my first Node Web server: ${inBody}`
            );
        }
    );
}).listen(9000);
```

I changed the following line in my **package.json**:

```
"start": "node server_time.js",
```

However, Node still seems to pick up **server.js** instead. I tried `npm cache verify`, `npm cache clear --force`, `rm -rf node_modules`, `rm package-lock.json`, and `npm install` again, but the problem didn't seem to go away. I even removed **package.json** and redefined it, but the value of `start` when I call `npm start` is still stale.

Here's an output from my shell:

```
GsMacbookPro:MyFirstNodeProject g$ cat package.json
{
  "name": "myfirstnodeproject",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "description": "Learning node",
  "main": "index.js",
  "start": "node server_time.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "G",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "request": "^2.88.2"
  }
}
GsMacbookPro:MyFirstNodeProject g$ ls
node_modules        package-lock.json   package.json        server.js       server_time.js
GsMacbookPro:MyFirstNodeProject g$ npm start

> myfirstnodeproject@1.0.1 start /Users/g/Repos/MyFirstNodeProject
> node server.js
```

Before someone asks, node version is **v10.16.3**, and npm version is **6.9.0**.

Comment: By the way, `start` should go under `scripts`, similar to what you have for `test`

Comment: @goto1 is correct. The default start script is node server.js ... that’s why it keeps running that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why `npm start` currently works for you is because `npm` will default some script values based on package contents.

> If there is a server.js file in the root of your package, then npm will default the start command to `node server.js`.

See here:

- [npm.js - default values](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#default-values)

So your `start` field inside `package.json` wasn't actually doing anything because it was not under `scripts`, which is where it should belong.

The correct approach is to update your `package.json` so that it looks like the following:

```
{
  "name": "myfirstnodeproject",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "description": "Learning node",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server_time.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "G",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "request": "^2.88.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: It was working because node server.js is the default start script in your case

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
{
    "name": "myfirstnodeproject",
    "version": "1.0.1",
    "description": "Learning node",
    "main": "server_time.js",
    "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
        "start": "node server_time.js"
    },
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "request": "^2.88.2"
    }
}
```

and then `npm run start`.

Comment: As per https://stackoverflow.com/a/51358329/2474507, `npm start` is merely an alias for `npm run start`. But I agree, keeping `start` at the root level was faulty.