# How to start custom package.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, package.json

How to start my package.json

My index.js in "client/js/index.js"

```
"scripts": {
"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
"start": "????"
}
```

Comment: What type of project is this? node? angular? other...

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn I see `echo`, I guess it's PHP

Comment: @Tân echo is a bash command

Answer (score 2):

In order to start the `index.js` file:

```
"start": "node client/js/index.js"
```

To run:

```
npm start
```

Comment: Can you help with script ?

Comment: Please provide more details to get help in the script. Or perhaps start another question

Comment: why not `npm run start`?

Comment: @MoloF it's the same. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51358235/difference-between-npm-start-and-npm-run-start

Answer (score 0):

As this is a node project your start should look like this:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
  "start": "node client/js/index.js"
}
```

you can then run

```
npm start
```